# Sort Multidimensional Dict in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort this dict based on the key "**order**". Kindly, find below sample dict :-

```
{'about-us': [{'name': 'CONSTITUTION', 'order': u'2', 'uri': 'constitution'},
              {'name': 'EXECUTIVE COMMITTEE',
               'order': u'3',
               'uri': 'executive-committee'},
              {'name': 'FINANCIAL INFO',
               'order': u'4',
               'uri': 'financial-info'},
              {'name': 'SPONSORS AND AFFILIATIONS',
               'order': u'5',
               'uri': 'sponsors-and-affiliations'},
              {'name': 'ABOUT', 'order': u'1', 'uri': 'about'}]}
```

Tried using this code, but I got an error

```
sorted(sub_links, key=lambda x: sub_links[x]['order'])
```

**TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str**

Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't sort the dictionary itself. Dictionary in python does not have an order.

- Trying to sort dictionary will pass keys of the dictionary to the `key` function. `sub_links[x]` => `sub_links['about-us']`; `sub_links[x]['order']` fails because `sub_links[x]` returns a  list.

You can sort the list inside the dictionary: `d['about-us']`

---

Also the usage of the `sorted` function should be changed: [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) passes each item to the key function, not the index of the item.

```
>>> sorted(d['about-us'], key=lambda x: int(x['order']))
[{'uri': 'about', 'name': 'ABOUT', 'order': u'1'},
 {'uri': 'constitution', 'name': 'CONSTITUTION', 'order': u'2'},
 {'uri': 'executive-committee', 'name': 'EXECUTIVE COMMITTEE', 'order': u'3'},
 {'uri': 'financial-info', 'name': 'FINANCIAL INFO', 'order': u'4'},
 {'uri': 'sponsors-and-affiliations', 'name': 'SPONSORS AND AFFILIATIONS', 'order': u'5'}]
```

If you need to sort all the dictionary values in place, loop over the values.

```
for value in d.values(): # use `itervalues` In Python 2.x
    value.sort(key=lambda x: int(x['order']))
```

Comment: Downvoter: Please let me know if there's anything wrong.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. 'order' is still not an integer

Comment: @RichardMiles, Yes, `order` itself is not an integer; so I added `int` call. `int(x['order'])`

Comment: @RichardMiles, OP's question is not about changing the `order` to int. It's about sorting by `order`. If that was an issue, OP (skycrew) didn't accept the answer.

Comment: That wasn't the problem either. Rather it was the error that prevented the desired functionality from being achieved. e.g. - `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`  The above solution does not solve this particular error, and because of this is not a viable solution for a problem as a whole.

Comment: @RichardMiles, Please try this: http://ideone.com/ecVKxK . I don't understand what you mean. Could you post an answer that you think correct?

Comment: @RichardMiles, I updated the answer to make it clearer. Please suggest edit if you have better idea.

Answer (score 0):

falsetru showed what you probably meant to do, but here's an explanation of the error you are seeing:

The `key` lambda function receives the dictionary's keys as its argument `x` when called--in this case, the call looks something like this when performed on the one and only key in the dictionary:

```
# this is JUST for demonstrating the execution of the code--this is not actual Python code
lambda("about-us"):
    return sub_links["about-us"]["order"]
```

When this executes, `sub_links["about-us"]` returns the value of that key, which is a list. When the next part of the statement executes (`<the list that got returned>["order"]`), the `TypeError` gets thrown because lists require integer indices.

There's a bigger problem here--it seems you called `sorted` on the whole dictionary, which only contains 1 value. It doesn't make sense to sort something with only 1 entry, and it should not be used to sort what you seem to want to sort, which is the inner list of dictionaries.

If you want to sort the inner list of dictionaries (the corresponding dict value for the "about-us" key), you'll need something like this (as falsetru also suggested):

```
sorted(sub_links["about-us"], key=lambda d: int(d["order"]))
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. There's syntax error in the first code. 1) the parameter of the lambda is string. 2) `lambda` should be one line (unless it is explicitly line-continued) 3) no statement is allowed in `lambda` (`return`)

Comment: It's just for demonstrating the way the code executes. It is not meant to be actual written code. But it is helpful to see how the `lambda` consumes the parameter and returns a value (since `lambda`s are so terse).